# Changing from letter characters to mathematical symbols from an Abstract Syntax Tree

Tags: c, types, stack, abstract-syntax-tree

For my final project in my C class, we are to change a reverse polish notation equation from reverse polish notation into its corresponding infix form. I'm currently having the issue that I'm trying to juggle characters and integers, as arguments such as +, -, /, and * are passed as A,S,D, and X respectively.

I'm fairly certain I'm doing something very dumb with my types which is causing the issue, but currently when I input ./rpcalc 5 4 A it returns 0 5 4. While I technically want it to be returning A 5 4, my ultimate goal is for the A to be returned as an addition symbol. However, I can't seem to get it past the current testing because all the letters I give it are returned as 0s. What am I doing incorrectly?

Below are the two struct nodes I'm using to represent my stack and my tree:

```
struct snode{
  int datum;
  struct snode* bottom;
};

struct tnode
{
  int datum;
  struct tnode* left;
  struct tnode* right;
};
```

I'm also using fairly standard push, peek, and pop functions, seen below:

```
int
peek(struct snode *stack){
  return stack -> datum;
}

struct snode*
pop(struct snode*stack){
  struct snode* tmp = NULL;
  if(stack == NULL){
    return NULL;
  }else{
    tmp = stack -> bottom;
    stack -> bottom = NULL;
    free(stack);
    stack = tmp;
    return stack;
  }
}

struct snode*
push(struct snode *stack, int x){
  struct snode* tmp = NULL;
  tmp = (struct snode*)malloc(sizeof(struct snode));
  tmp -> bottom = stack;
  tmp -> datum = x;
  stack = tmp;
  return stack;
}
```

To build up the Abstract Syntax Tree, I use 2 functions, create_node and gen_tree, seen below.

```
struct tnode*
create_node(int x){
  struct tnode* tmp;
  tmp = (struct tnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
  tmp -> datum = x;
  tmp -> right = NULL;
  tmp -> left = NULL;
  return tmp;
}


struct tnode*
gen_tree(struct snode *S){
  if(S==NULL){
    return NULL;
  }else{
    int top;
    top = peek(S);
    if(isdigit(top)){
      S = pop(S);
      return create_node(top);
    }else{
      struct tnode *root = create_node(top);
      S = pop(S);
      root -> right = gen_tree(S);
      S = pop(S);
      root -> left = gen_tree(S);
      return root;
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, my main final takes arguments from argv and puts them onto a stack. Once this stack has been fully generated (all arguments from argv have been read), it uses them to generate the tree. Afterwards, for testing purposes before I attempt to write the function to use this tree to generate an infix function, I print the table using the print_table function.

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
  int i = 1;
  struct snode*stack;
  struct tnode *AST;

  while(argv[i] != NULL){
    stack = push(stack, atol(argv[i]));
    i++
  }

  AST = gen_tree(stack);
  print_table(AST);

  return 0;
}

void
print_table(struct tnode*AST){
  if(AST != NULL){
  print_table(AST->left);
  printf("%d", AST->datum);
  print_table(AST->right);
}
```

Like I said, I'm fairly certain I'm just doing something very dumb with my types, I'm just not sure how exactly to carry the information properly. What should I be doing? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're storing either an integer or an operator, surely `int` is not the proper data type for `datum`. Maybe have two members `intval` and `opval`? Also you shouldn't blindly pass `argv[i]` to `atol` because `atol` returns 0 if it doesn't find any digits (e.g. when you pass it `"A"`).